# Will two RAND() functions in the same formula produce two separate random numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, random-number-generator

I am reviewing someone else's work without them being easily able to answer. The formula below should not produce results less than zero as it is related to a physical quantity that cannot be negative. However it is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(((RAND()-0.5)*J6*I6)<0,0,(RAND()-0.5)*J6*I6),0)
```

Both the column "J" and "I" numbers are all positive. I assume it is because the two `RAND()` functions are separate from each other and therefore are in fact two different random numbers each time it calculates. Is this the case?

In which case a separate column with the `RAND()` functions and this one referencing them would work?

Comment: Thank you two both of the answers. I could only choose one and don't have reputation to upvote yet. Thank you also to the editor of my question. Still need to learn how to make it look like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, I wrote a sum of two random integer numbers in Excel. The result would be always even, if the random number generator would re-use the same value in a given expression. But it isn't!

So, your assumption is correct: Each call provides a fresh independent value.

To use a separate cell would in fact put the same value twice into your expression.
You could extract the complete sub-expression `(RAND()-0.5)*J6*I6)` to improve readability of your formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put in a cell `RAND()-RAND()`. You will see that the value is not null. Then `RAND` is called two time and return two different values.

Answer (score 0):

If you NEED it to be the same value both times, and have the `LET()` function available, you could use:

```
=LET(Value,RAND(),

     IFERROR(  IF(  ((Value-0.5)*J6*I6)<0,  0,  (Value-0.5)*J6*I6),  0)
 )
```

This works the way it looks and sounds like you desire it to work. The reason is that one of the points of `LET()` is to allow a variable to be set in order to calculate it only once, rather than every time the value in question is needed in the formula.

You are harnessing that by using the single result in both places in the formula.